# Extract specific JARs from dependencies

Tags: gradle

I am new to gradle but learning quickly.  I need to get some specific JARs from logback into a new directory in my release task.  The dependencies are resolving OK, but I can't figure out how, in the release task, to extract just logback-core-1.0.6.jar and logback-access-1.0.6.jar into a directory called 'lib/ext'.  Here are the relevant excerpts from my build.gradle.

```
dependencies {
    ...
    compile 'org.slf4j:slf4j-api:1.6.4'
    compile 'ch.qos.logback:logback-core:1.0.6'
    compile 'ch.qos.logback:logback-classic:1.0.6'
    runtime 'ch.qos.logback:logback-access:1.0.6'
    ...
}
...
task release(type: Tar, dependsOn: war) {
    extension = "tar.gz"
    classifier = project.classifier
    compression = Compression.GZIP

    into('lib') {
        from configurations.release.files
        from configurations.providedCompile.files
    }

    into('lib/ext') {
        // TODO:  Right here I want to extract just logback-core-1.0.6.jar and logback-access-1.0.6.jar
    }
    ...
}
```

How do I iterated over the dependencies to locate those specific files and drop them in the lib/ext directory created by into('lib/ext')?

Answer (score 21, accepted):

[Configurations](http://gradle.org/docs/current/dsl/org.gradle.api.artifacts.Configuration.html) are just (lazy) collections. You can iterate over them, filter them, etc. Note that you typically only want to do this in the *execution phase* of the build, not in the *configuration phase*. The code below achieves this by using the lazy [FileCollection.filter()](http://gradle.org/docs/current/javadoc/org/gradle/api/file/FileCollection.html#filter(groovy.lang.Closure)) method. Another approach would have been to pass a *closure* to the [Tar.from()](http://gradle.org/docs/current/dsl/org.gradle.api.tasks.bundling.Tar.html#org.gradle.api.tasks.bundling.Tar:from(java.lang.Object...)) method.

```
task release(type: Tar, dependsOn: war) {
    ...
    into('lib/ext') {
        from findJar('logback-core') 
        from findJar('logback-access')
    }
}

def findJar(prefix) { 
    configurations.runtime.filter { it.name.startsWith(prefix) }
}
```

Answer (score 9):

It is worth nothing that the accepted answer filters the `Configuration` as a `FileCollection` so within the collection you can only access the attributes of a file. If you want to filter on the dependency itself (on group, name, or version) rather than its filename in the cache then you can use something like:

```
task copyToLib(type: Copy) {
  from findJarsByGroup(configurations.compile, 'org.apache.avro')
  into "$buildSrc/lib"
}

def findJarsByGroup(Configuration config, groupName) {
  configurations.compile.files { it.group.equals(groupName) }
}
```

`files` takes a dependencySpecClosure which is just a filter function on a `Dependency`, see: https://gradle.org/docs/current/javadoc/org/gradle/api/artifacts/Dependency.html