# Cannot change dependencies of configuration

Tags: intellij-idea, gradle, gretty

After I added  `copyBootstrap` to `build.gradle` I am getting the next error when try to run the *build* task:

> FAILURE: Build failed with an exception.
>
> - What went wrong:
>
> A problem occurred configuring root project '.
>   Cannot change dependencies of configuration ':providedCompile' after it has been included in dependency resolution.

How could this issue be solved? I have searched on Internet but no solutions were found. I got the `copyBootstrap` task from [this link](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/39469010/how-to-refer-to-bootstraps-css-which-was-downloaded-as-gradle-dependency). Their goal is to extract all content from `org.webjars` group jars to a specific path.

I am using **Gradle 3.2** and Intellij IDEA 2016.2.5

```
//group 'org'
//version '1.0-SNAPSHOT'

task wrapper(type: Wrapper) {
  gradleVersion = '3.2'
  distributionUrl = "https://services.gradle.org/distributions/gradle-$gradleVersion-all.zip"
}


buildscript {
    repositories {
        jcenter()
    }

    dependencies {
        classpath 'org.akhikhl.gretty:gretty:1.4.0'
    }
}

repositories {
    mavenCentral()
    jcenter()
}

//apply plugin: 'java'
//apply plugin: 'eclipse-wtp'
//apply from: 'https://raw.github.com/akhikhl/gretty/master/pluginScripts/gretty.plugin'
apply plugin: 'war'
apply plugin: 'org.akhikhl.gretty'


sourceCompatibility = 1.8
targetCompatibility = 1.8

dependencies {

    //compile group: 'org.akhikhl.gretty', name: 'gretty', version: '1.4.0'


    // ********************************************************************************************************
    // SPRING FRAMEWORK, ORM Y H2DB
    // ********************************************************************************************************

    compile group: 'org.springframework', name: 'spring-webmvc', version: '4.3.4.RELEASE'
    compile group: 'org.springframework', name: 'spring-orm', version: '4.3.4.RELEASE'
    compile group: 'org.springframework', name: 'spring-jdbc', version: '4.3.4.RELEASE'
    compile group: 'org.hibernate', name: 'hibernate-core', version: '5.2.3.Final'


    // ********************************************************************************************************
    // JACKSON DATABIND
    // ********************************************************************************************************

    compile group: 'com.fasterxml.jackson.core', name: 'jackson-core', version: '2.8.4'
    compile group: 'com.fasterxml.jackson.core', name: 'jackson-databind', version: '2.8.4'


    // ********************************************************************************************************
    // THYMELEAF
    // ********************************************************************************************************

    compile group: 'org.thymeleaf', name: 'thymeleaf-spring4', version: '3.0.2.RELEASE'


    // ********************************************************************************************************
    // SERVLET
    // ********************************************************************************************************

    compile group: 'javax.servlet', name: 'javax.servlet-api', version: '3.1.0'


    // ********************************************************************************************************
    // MYSQL CONNECTOR
    // ********************************************************************************************************

    //compile group: 'mysql', name: 'mysql-connector-java', version: '6.0.5' issues with time zone
    compile 'mysql:mysql-connector-java:5.1.6'

    // ********************************************************************************************************
    // WEB RESOURCES
    // ********************************************************************************************************

    compile group: 'org.webjars', name: 'angularjs', version: '1.5.8'
    compile group: 'org.webjars', name: 'jquery', version: '2.1.4'
    compile group: 'org.webjars', name: 'bootstrap', version: '3.3.7'
    compile group: 'org.webjars', name: 'jquery-ui', version: '1.12.1'
    compile group: 'org.webjars', name: 'modernizr', version: '2.8.3'


    // ********************************************************************************************************
    // JUNIT AND SPRING TEST
    // ********************************************************************************************************

    testCompile group: 'junit', name: 'junit', version: '4.12'
    testCompile group: 'org.springframework', name: 'spring-test', version: '4.3.4.RELEASE'


    // ********************************************************************************************************
    // GOOGLE DRIVE API
    // ********************************************************************************************************

    compile group: 'com.google.api-client', name: 'google-api-client', version: '1.22.0'
    compile group: 'com.google.apis', name: 'google-api-services-drive', version: 'v2-rev245-1.22.0'
    compile group: 'com.google.api-client', name: 'google-api-client-java6', version: '1.22.0'
    compile group: 'com.google.oauth-client', name: 'google-oauth-client-jetty', version: '1.22.0'


    // ********************************************************************************************************
    // DROPBOX API
    // ********************************************************************************************************

    compile group: 'com.dropbox.core', name: 'dropbox-core-sdk', version: '1.8.2'


    // ********************************************************************************************************
    // TWITTER API
    // ********************************************************************************************************

    compile group: 'org.twitter4j', name: 'twitter4j-core', version: '4.0.5'


//    compile group: 'org.slf4j', name: 'slf4j-mylearn.api', version: '1.7.21'
//    compile group: 'org.slf4j', name: 'slf4j-log4j12', version: '1.7.21'

//    compile files("twitter/main/webapp/") // add this path as a classpath

}


task copyBootstrap(type: Copy) {
    into "$buildDir/static_resources"
    configurations.compile
            .files({ it.group.equals("org.webjars")})
            .each {
        from zipTree(it)
    }
}

//build.dependsOn(copyBootstrap)

task copyToLib2(type: Copy) {
    into "$buildDir/output/libs"
    from configurations.runtime
}

war {
  archiveName = 'ROOT.war'
  destinationDir = file('webapps')
}


// ********************************************************************************************************
// GRETTY SETTINGS
// ********************************************************************************************************

/* Change context path (base url). otherwise defaults to name of project */
gretty {
    port = 8081
    contextPath = ''
}
```

Answer (score 2):

This problem seems to be related to the `org.akhikhl.gretty` plugin you are trying to use. If I try to build a project using the above gradle file I get the following output:

```
C:\ws\PLAYGROUND\test123>gradle wrapper --stacktrace
Changed dependencies of configuration ':providedCompile' after it has been included in dependency resolution. This behaviour has been deprecated and is cheduled to be removed in Gradle 3.0.
Changed dependencies of parent of configuration ':compile' after it has been resolved. This behaviour has been deprecated and is scheduled to be removed in Gradle 3.0
Changed strategy of configuration ':compile' after it has been resolved. This behaviour has been deprecated and is scheduled to be removed in Gradle 3.0
Changed dependencies of configuration ':grettyProvidedCompile' after it has been included in dependency resolution. This behaviour has been deprecated and is scheduled to be removed in Gradle 3.0.

⋮

* Exception is:
org.gradle.api.ProjectConfigurationException: A problem occurred configuring root project 'test123'.
    at org.gradle.configuration.project.LifecycleProjectEvaluator.addConfigurationFailure(LifecycleProjectEvaluator.java:79)
    at org.gradle.configuration.project.LifecycleProjectEvaluator.notifyAfterEvaluate(LifecycleProjectEvaluator.java:74)
    at org.gradle.configuration.project.LifecycleProjectEvaluator.evaluate(LifecycleProjectEvaluator.java:61)
    ⋮
Caused by: org.gradle.api.InvalidUserDataException: Cannot change dependencies of configuration ':compile' after it has been resolved.
    at org.gradle.api.internal.artifacts.configurations.DefaultConfiguration.validateMutation(DefaultConfiguration.java:578)
    at org.gradle.api.internal.artifacts.configurations.DefaultConfiguration$2.run(DefaultConfiguration.java:137)
    ⋮
    at org.akhikhl.gretty.GrettyPlugin$_addDependencies_closure11.doCall(GrettyPlugin.groovy:130)
    ⋮
```

That is the gretty plugin seems to use functionality that has been removed with gradle 3.0

There is [issue #306](https://github.com/akhikhl/gretty/issues/306) that has been reported a short time ago which describes pretty much your problem.

Given the number of open issues for such a small project and the lack of activity on the issues, I don't think this plugin is much of a help and you will probably be better off using something different.